# How to avoid turning my whole code into static

Tags: c#, xamarin

Am inheriting an interface called ISurfaceTextureListener in this code

```
class Camera
{
    TextureView mTextureView;
    Context _context;
    public Camera (Context context, TextureView textureView)
    {
        _context = context;
        mTextureView = textureView;
        mTextureView.SurfaceTextureListener = new TextureViewListener();
    }
    private class TextureViewListener : Java.Lang.Object, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
    {
        public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            OpenCamera(width, height); //Error Occurring Here 
        }
    }
    public void OpenCamera(int width, int height)
    {
        //Codes 
    }
}
```

> Error : an object reference is required to access non-static field,
>   method etc..

I don't want to make OpenCamera() static because I will have to turn my whole code into static methods ,, so is there a way to avoid it ?

NOTE: am only inheriting the interface because I can't override object listener's "OnSurfaceTextureAvailable" method, the only way I found is to assign an inherited class for the object's listener and it worked just fine .

Comment: Where does OpenCamera() live? Can you include that code in the post?

Comment: you have to make a instance of the class where OpenCamera belongs then call OpenCamera on that object.

Comment: That error is weird, if you're on an instance function as you posted any non-static member must be already available as "this" is assumed when no instance is explicitly used. Add more code to understand why that error can happen (the OpenCamera function at least).

Comment: thanks guys,I modified the code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is the exact opposite of what you think it is.  It is not a hint that you should make `OpenCamera()` static;  it is a hint that you are trying to access it as if it was static, while in fact it is not.

You need `someObjectIhaventToldYouAnythingAbout.OpenCamera(width, height);`

**EDIT**

So, after your comment and your edits, where you are essentially telling us  about `someObjectIhaventToldYouAnythingAbout`, it appears that you should be doing this:

```
    mTextureView.SurfaceTextureListener = new TextureViewListener( this );
}
private class TextureViewListener : Java.Lang.Object, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
{
     readonly Camera camera;

     TextureViewListener( Camera camera )
     {
         this.camera = camera;
     }

    public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
    {
        camera.OpenCamera(width, height); //Error Occurring Here 
    }
}
public void OpenCamera(int width, int height)
{
    //Codes 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , when I change OpenCamera() to static the error is gone, anyway I added some more code it's a class within a class is that messed up ? please review the code

Comment: Well, yes, of course, if you make OpenCamera() static the error is gone, but this is the same as saying that if you don't like the tattoo on your hand, you can cut your hand, and then the tattoo is gone, but it is not a very good solution, is it? I amended my answer to show you what you should be doing instead.